# Multi-Part request in background

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, kotlin

This is more a question of software that a programming question, so making a multi-part request making that with the app open makes the user wait a bit, I can do a background task but I'm trying to keep the app api in 21(Android), what do a make in app open or I make a background that works with the app close and send the values until the file is ended?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of cases you can do.You can use: [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) or [Kotlin coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) (if you use Kotlin). Also you can try to use Koltin flow (similar to rxJava) but it's experimental yet.
If you need to make requests to rest api one by one you can do it with coroutines. All you need it's:

1. Add "suspend" keyword to method
2. Start it on View Scope or somewhere else

For rest api calls I recommend using [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). This library can deserialise responses to pojo (for example with GsonConverterFactory). Also you can use "suspend" there

Comment: That part I know i need just make a decision so if I use background part do make, or if I let the user see that, because the file is large